# to change the default where the projects are stored in VS 2008

Tags: .net

In VS 2008 how how do I change the default folder where the projects are stored??

Right now they are stored in My Documents/VS 2008/Projects

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to tools => Options => Project and Solutions

Answer (score 1):

while creating Project change the path in location to store your project